# How would a fluid having a vortex act under free fall?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, torque, fluid-statics, flow

Let us say we have an enclosed cylinder containing an ideal fluid , and we "swirl the fluid" such that a vortex is formed in the cylinder and the sides of the vortex are almost on the verge of sliing out if the container.

**What would happen if we were to take this apparatus to an adequate height above the ground,and as soon as we leave the container(with the base of the container parallel to the ground),the container vanishes, such that the entire liquid is now exposed to the surroundings?**

Now what would tried this experiment under a host of conditions like:

- Neglecting air resistance
- Replacing the ideal fluid with lets say,     water or glycerine
- Making the container spin on an arbritary axis just before "vanishing" it
- Flipping the container upside down such that the opening of the vortex faces the ground

Comment: What do **you** think will happen?

Comment: Is the cylinder an essential part of the question, or just the motion of a vortex through an ideal fluid?

Comment: @Sam To be honest I'm not quite sure. Neglecting air resistance,I would expect the fluid to start dissipating horizontally while there is no change in the vertical components.But at the same time if you were to consider factors like air resistance and the angular spin provided,it could also probably shape itself into 2 joined spheres with an increasing clevage between them.

Comment: @D.Halsey It's not an essential part, just the fluid having a vortex in freefall. I felt that a cylinder would probably make the explanation easier.